# Creating JSON document using foreach loop

Tags: java, json

I am trying to fetch the data from the database and then trying to set the values in the JSON document using ArrayList but i am not able to do that.
Lets say this is hard code JSON which i want to convert it into dynamic JSON
view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
String json = "{ \"demo\":[[ \"Sam\",\"Sola\",\"Accun\"],[\"Raj\",\"Sanjosh\",\"CA\"],[\"Karan\",\"Toshi\",\"Java\"]]}";
```

Now, to embed the JSON rows dynamically , i have used ArrayList as follows :
view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();  

.............some database code..........  

while (result.next()) {  

al.add("[ \"" + result.getString(1) + "\",  
              \""+ result.getString(3) + "\",  
              \"" + result.getString(4)+ "\",  
              \"" + result.getString(5) + "\",  
              \""+ result.getString(6) + "\",  
              \"" + result.getString(7)+ "\",  
              \"" + result.getString(8) + "\"]");  

}
```

Now i want to embed this collection into the JSON document. but not sure how to do this.
view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
    String h =  "{ \"demo\":[ "+  
        for(Object o : al){  

        }  
         +"]}";
```

Please Guide me to get through this....Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually trying to construct the json, you would be better off using one of the existing libraries.  It looks like the json you are trying to generate is a simple mapping, so you could do something like this:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(result.getString(1));
    list.add(result.getString(3));
    //etc
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map.put("demo", list);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(map);
```

Comment: wow..thanks..never thought Map can be implemented this way...Thanks for the Heads Up dear...shall try to implement this code...Cheers!!